# How to create a validity.php file

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to link the home.php and login.php file i created to my validation file but it is not working. It is showing Warning: include(location:login.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\userregistration\validation.php on line 21

```
<?php 
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con, 'userregistration');
$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$s = " select * from usertable where name = '$name' && password='pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($num == 1){
    include 'location:home.php';
}else{
    include 'location:login.php';       
}   
?>
```

Comment: include("login.php"); only .. remove location:

Comment: or they are not in same folder

Comment: thank you Danish Hakim. The error message has been removed but its showing me a blank page please help

Comment: Share your `include` or `request` codes

Comment: elliotching they are actually in the same folder.

Comment: <?php


session_start();


?>


<html>

<head>

<title> Home page </title>


</head>

<body>

<h1>welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> </h1>

</body>

</html>

Comment: @MarcoSanchez this is the home.php file codes.

Comment: @KajangPrince `I have been trying to link the home.php and login.php file i created to my validation file` But I don't see any `include` or `request` in your code. How are you trying to `link` your pages?

Comment: @MarcoSanchez here is the validation codes

<?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'userregistration');

$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$s = " select * from usertable where name = '$name' && password='pass'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){
 ("home.php");
}else{
    ("login.php");  
} 

?>

Comment: Instead of `include 'location:login.php';`, you should use `header('Location: login.php');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in the code you shared. I found a typo:

```
                                                          // missed $ in $pass
    $s = " select * from usertable where name = '$name' && password='pass'";
```

Then

```
    if ($num == 1) {
        ("home.php"); //<-- here try: header("location:./home.php");
    } else {
        ("login.php"); //<-- here try: header("location:./login.php");
    }
```